# Redirecting a URL from one domain to another in Apache containing character #

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I was trying to use Apache mod_rewrite for redirecting URLs from one domain (e.g. `pesdevelopment.ktm.local`) to another domain (`pestest.ktm.local`).

Therefore I have used the following condition and rule within Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pesdevelopment\.ktm\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pestest.ktm.local/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The problem is that URLs that are containing the character # are not redirected correctly. The character is stopping the rewrite process and it is redirected to the URL that was rewritten so far until the character has appeared in the URL.

Example: 
`The URL pesdevelopment.ktm.local/Windchill/app/#ptc1/` is redirected to `pestest.ktm.local/Windchill/app/`

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pesdevelopment\.ktm\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pestest.ktm.local/$1%1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Did you try doing a hard refresh of the page?

Comment: Yes I have tried a hard refresh. But it is jumping to pestest.ktm.local/Windchill/app/ coming from http://pesdevelopment.ktm.local/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=OR%3Awt.epm.EPMDocument%3A585162223&u8=1 Any idea?

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess? I tried the link `beta.myssite.com/Windchill/app/#ptc1/tcomp/infoPage?oid=OR%3Awt.epm.EPMDocument%3A585162223&u8=1` and it redirected it fine.

Comment: No there are not rules in the htaccess